# digitalwrite with function parameter as parameter

Tags: digitalwrite

Firstly, excuse my poor English, this is not my native langage.

I'm trying to use an Arduino Uno to drive an 8 relay board from an MQTT Subscription. I ask for help because i'm some kind of beginner in arduino, i'm just a Linux addict.

The idea is to get a payload from PubSubclient and use it to manage relays.
For example, the payload '71' ask the relay 7 to turn on and '42' make the relay 4 to turn off.

All works fine until I wanted to write a function with two parameters : 'relay_number' and 'Action'

All parameters are received but the relay never goes up or down.

My code :

```
void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  
  Relay_Nb = (char)payload[0];
  Action = char(payload[1]);

  Serial.println(Relay_Nb);
  Serial.println(Action);
  
  RelayControl(Relay_Nb, Action);
}

void RelayControl(char Relay_Nb, char Action) {
  Serial.println(Relay_Nb);   // for debugging purpose
  Serial.println(Action);
   
  if ( Action == '0') {
    Serial.print("Bringing down Relay ");
    Serial.println(Relay_Nb);
    digitalWrite(Relay_Nb, LOW); 
  } else if (Action == '1') {
    Serial.print("Bringing up Relay ");
    Serial.println(Relay_Nb);
    digitalWrite(Relay_Nb, HIGH);
  } else if (Action == '2') {
    // Relay temporisé (ouverture portail par ex)
    Serial.println("Bringing up, and down Relay ");
    digitalWrite(Relay_Nb, HIGH);
    delay(750);
    digitalWrite(Relay_Nb, LOW);
  } 
}
```

I'm sure an old maker have the solution i'm searching for hours now.

Please help and don't hesitate to show me others ways.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the serial output?

Comment: Relay_Nb is the character 1 or 0, not the value 1 or 0?

Comment: The serial output is for debugging purpose.
Character or value is probably the problem, but what have i to do to change this?

Comment: your callback function makes an assumption about the data ... there is no check for unexpected data

Comment: You're right.I'll write it after the relay issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending the parameter `Relay_Nb` as a character, and then using it as an integer.

You need to turn the character into an integer - and the simplest way is to subtract the ASCII value of `0` from it:

```
Relay_Nb = payload[0] - '0';
```

But with that said, a note on how you have written your callback:

- You aren't checking the data is valid.

You should really be doing, at the very least, the following:

1. Check that the `length` parameter is at least `2`,
2. Check that the two data values are within the correct range for your function

Comment: It works fine, you're my hero.
I just don't understand how. Where can I find some explaination ?
I can now start the security checks.

Comment: @Pwol: `man ascii`, and look for the code points of the digits.

Comment: @EdgarBonet You're assuming he's using a real operating system, not some toy like Windows.

Comment: @Majenko: He wrote “_i'm just a Linux addict_”.

Comment: @EdgarBonet True. I tuned out at "I ask for help because..."

Comment: Any reason ot use `'0'` subtraction in preference to the `atoi()` function? i.e. `int Relay_Nb = atoi(payload[0]);`

Comment: @PeterFeerick `atoi()` expects a string, not a character.

Comment: Or `Relay_Nb = payload[0] & byte(0x0f);` That's why ASCII for 0 to 9 was encoded as 0x30 to 0x39, i.e. easy conversion between bytes and characters.